# EnvironmentObject updated in view but not in root app file

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm encountering a very strange problem in my SwiftUI app.

I'm trying to save some user data informations thanks to json serialization. So I created a UserData class which is passed as an environment object and accessible in all my application :

(I intentionally simplify the code by removing the data saving and loading part from the main app file)

```
class UserData: ObservableObject, Codable {
    var pots: Set<Pot>
    
    init(pots: Set<Pot>) {
        self.pots = pots
    }
}
```

```
struct Pot: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable{
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let description: String
    var currentMoneyAmout: Float
    let potImage: URL
    let gift: Gift
    let members: [Member]
    let ownerId: String
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }

    static func == (lhs: Pot, rhs: Pot) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id && lhs.title == rhs.title
    }
}

extension Pot{
    static let previewPot = Pot(
        title: "Cadeau coco",
        description: "Cadeau pour l'anniversaire de coco",
        currentMoneyAmout: 30,
        potImage: URL(string: "https://montetasoiree.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/img_home_intro.jpg")!,
        gift: .previewGift,
        members: [.previewMember],
        ownerId: "a"
    )
}
```

```
@main
struct PotivApp: App {
    
    @State private var userData = UserData(pots: [])
    
    init(){
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContainerView()
                .environmentObject(userData)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I get this UserData object in a view in order to update it :

```
struct newPot: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var userData: UserData
            
    var body: some View {
        VStack{    
            Spacer()

            Button{
                savePot()
                dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Créer")
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 50)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(.infinity)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    private func savePot() {  
        let pot = Pot.previewPot
        
        self.userData.pots.insert(pot)
        self.userData.objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
```

When I print my userData pots in this view, it contains the new pot I just create. But when I try to print the pots in my main app file, it don't contain the new pot and I really don't understand why.

First, I though the two UserData objects were not the same. But after checking it, they are.

Did someone have an idea ?

Comment: Try `@StateObject` instead of `@State`

Comment: Don't override `Hashable` and `Equatable` you are quite literally telling SwiftUI never to reload because the `id` never changes.

Answer (score 0):

you should make pods @Published

```
class UserData: ObservableObject, Codable {
    @Published var pots: Set<Pot>
    // ...
}
```

once you use @Published you can remove self.userData.objectWillChange.send()
the view will know that the @published var changed

further @State are for simple data

```
@main
struct PotivApp: App {
    @StateObject private var userData = UserData(pots: [])
    // ...
}
```